# How to use Radio Group and Radio buttons and get a string value

Tags: android

I have a switch statement set up with a if(checked) inside them, and all I am trying to do is to change a string variable labeled category to the corresponding switch statement.

I can't figure out how to get the variable information outside of the onRadioClicked object into the variable.

I am extremely new to Android and Java itself, I know C# and that's about it.

In C# I would of created the switch, have category = "xxx"; and problem solved.

I'm using Android 3.4, programming for API 21 (Lolipop) and I have tried the equivalent to the C# way. I also trying setting up a public onRadioButtonClicked and had returns inside my switches, but that doesn't seem to work either.

My assignment is being posted to a html server with google volley, and one of the requirements is getting a selection from a radio group to send with the rest of the information (everything else seems to work)

my code is:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.film:
                if (checked)

                break;
            case R.id.actor:
                if (checked)

                break;
            case R.id.actress:
                if (checked)

                break;
            case R.id.editing:
                if (checked)

                break;
            case R.id.effects:
                if (checked)

                break;
```

and I have a variable defined as 
public String category;
which is placed under mainActivity at the top of the page.

the expected results to the server should be one of the following:

film, actor, actress, editing, effects

but I am getting ????

I know the issue is I am not passing anything back from the switch to the string at the top.

any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You've ensured your `onClick` method is being called?

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value in the switch case. You should assign a value to the global field as such:

```
    case R.id.film:
        if (checked)
           category = "film"    //assign whatever here
        break;
    case R.id.actor:
        if (checked)
           category = "actor"    // same thing here
        break;
```